# Why does Postfix change the message-id of my mails?

Tags: postfix

I have a firstline / graveyard system of Postfix. So, one server is the graveyard of the first line server. I managed this by setting the smtp_fallback_relay in the first line server.

So far, so good, the graveyard receives the emails rejected from the first, but I don't know why, it changes the original message-id of the message. Basically, it makes up a new message-id based on the date and hour, if I'm not wrong.

That's bad, because I'd like to keep track of the messages through this parameter.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to show proof that this happens.

I suspect you're confusing the SMTP Message-Id: header with the postfix Queue-ID.